# Registering with StackOverflow

Tags: discussion

If I go to the "log-in" page as a new user (https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) I'm presented with a page that doesn't obviously give me any way to register. 
The page tells me a little about openID, gives me an option to login directly or get my password recovered, however there's absolutely nothing on there for "register". If JavaScript is enabled I also get boxes for various OpenID sites, but still no "register" option

It seems you have to click on the "sign-in" button which in turn takes you to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login - which then has a register button which in turn points to: https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register .

I would posit there should be an easy-access register page that's not three clicks deep.

Comment: I'm not sure what the policy is for editing a question so I'll append this comment. Per my comment below, the issue is predominantly with JavaScript Off and doesn't happen with JavaScript On.

Comment: The policy is that edits to questions are encouraged. :-)

Answer (score 4):

[status-notabug](/questions/tagged/status-notabug)/[status-wontfix](/questions/tagged/status-wontfix)

Well, usually most people use GMail or Facebook or Yahoo, so they can just directly sign in--no need to "create" an SE account.

That being said,

> I'm presented with a page that doesn't obviously give me any way to register
>
> [...]
>
> three clicks deep.

[image]

Comment: +1 for almost readable freehand writing

Comment: @Manishearth - Interesting. Originally this bug was going to be a Javascript-Off bug, however I then decided to try it with JS on and due to the wonders of selective reading I didn't see it say "sign up" on that page. --- I've just confirmed it does **not** say sign up when you have javascript off (which was going to be my original report), it says "sign in". And that link itself takes you to a login page. The register page really is three pages deep for JS-off users.

Comment: I know that link too well...I always click it by accident when I aim for "Show more login options..." :(

Comment: Oh, and +1 for the tags!